# logistic regression - DV categories

Tags: categorical-data

I have a dichotomous dependent variable where 0 (reference category) has 69 cases and 1 has 393 cases (because I collapsed two categories- I originally ran a multinomial regression).

Could this unbalance cause any issues?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a dichotomous outcome the effective sample size is the minimum of the 0’s and the 1’s. So in your case it would be 69. The effective sample size relates to the amount of information you have available in your dependent variable and gives a guidance as to how many explanatory variables you could include in your regression model. A rule of thumb is that you can include $K$ coefficients in your model, where $K$ is the effective sample size divided by 10 or 15.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This is very helpful! Best regards